# How do you use their Fill Down (dragging formula thing) without copying cell styles / formatting?

Tags: google-sheets

Cannot find this anywhere I look. Lot of SEO spam on Google Sheets.

I have a table that has a ton of different styles:

| Header |
| --- |
| small font |
| BIG FONT |
| **bold font** |
| *italic font* |

The "small font" cell is a formula. I would like to "drag" the small font formula all the way down while maintaining the styling of all of the cells. If I do this, it makes all the cells "small font" styling too.

In Excel you can do this by right-clicking the "Fill Down" square and having multiple drag options.

I am open to other solutions of doing this quickly, but copying and then "Special Pasting" the formula only is a bit slow to productivity.

Answer (score 1):

In Google Sheets, you can use an array formula instead of manually filling down copies of the same formula separately in every cell.

So, instead of filling down a formula like `=A2 + B2` in cells `C2:C10`, insert this array formula in cell `C2`:

`=arrayformula( A2:A10 + B2:B10 )`

The formula will automatically fill cells `C2:C10` without modifying their formatting.

Comment: Not exactly what the OP was asking for, because cells whose values were calculated using an ArrayFormula (except the original cell) show just their values in Formula box, as opposed to the a formula used to calculate them. But I'm assuming this is the best answer because Sheets just doesn't provide a way to drag a formula without also copying formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it by dragging the fill handle. However, you can achieve a similar effect by doing the following:

1. Copy the cell whose formula you'd like to reproduce elsewhere.
2. Select the entire range of cells where you want to paste the formula into.
3. Right-click the selected cells and choose "Paste Special->Formula Only." This will reproduce the formula in every selected cell with appropriately updated cell references without copying the formatting.